# Grafana Notification channel adding in config?

Tags: notifications, kubernetes, grafana, channel

I have installed Grafana in Kubernetes. I am trying to do everything automaticaly by scripts.  I am able to intall grafana, import datasouce and dashobards.  But i would like to also add a Notification channel to slack BUT not in web UI but somewhere in the config.  It there any possibiluty to do that?

Jakub

Comment: Its an open request in grafana.  https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/10487. But if you like to sort of automate this, you may leverage the notification api.  http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/alerting/#create-alert-notification

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for now to use Grafana API:

```
POST /api/alert-notifications


{
  "name": "new alert notification",  //Required
  "type":  "email", //Required
  "isDefault": false,
  "sendReminder": false,
  "settings": {
    "addresses": "carl@grafana.com;dev@grafana.com"
  }
}
```

Docs http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/alerting/#get-alert-notifications

Answer (score 0):

I added nofitication channel with  curl (API) to grafana.

Answer (score 0):

Alerts can be provisioned.
Create a file at */etc/grafana/provisioning/notifiers/notifiers.yml*. Here's an example (copied from the official documentation). Possible settings can be found at the [Grafana Provisioning documentation page](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/provisioning/#alert-notification-channels):

```yaml
notifiers:
  - name: notification-channel-1
    type: slack
    uid: notifier1
    # either
    org_id: 2
    # or
    org_name: Main Org.
    is_default: true
    send_reminder: true
    frequency: 1h
    disable_resolve_message: false
    settings:
      recipient: 'XXX'
      uploadImage: true
      token: 'xoxb' # legacy setting since Grafana v7.2 (stored non-encrypted)
      url: https://slack.com # legacy setting since Grafana v7.2 (stored non-encrypted)
      # Secure settings that will be encrypted in the database 
      # (supported since Grafana v7.2). 
    secure_settings:
      token: 'xoxb'
      url: https://slack.com
```